# Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install'

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

So I have upgraded from Disco to Eoan, so far quite 'interesting' 
I needed to rebuild Grub to get a GUI - took a while but finished and I'm using the PC.
Today I've been getting numerous browser crashes so my first thought is to run both
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade.
That was a disappointing exercise.
here's the output from update 
"3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them."

so cool, I don't care what the packages are, just upgrade them so after I type in 
apt upgrade I see this in the terminal

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken
install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet
dependencies:  linux-image-generic : Depends:
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic but it is not installed E: Unmet
dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or
specify a solution).
```

This was unexpected so I did run apt --fix-broken install and lo !

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
required:   chromium-browser-l10n command-not-found-data diffstat
g++-8 gir1.2-mutter-4   intltool-debian libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg-perl
libapt-pkg5.0   libarchive-zip-perl libasync-mergepoint-perl
libb-hooks-op-check-perl   libcapture-tiny-perl libcgi-fast-perl
libcgi-pm-perl libclass-accessor-perl   libclass-method-modifiers-perl
libclass-xsaccessor-perl libclone-perl   libcrystalhd3
libdevel-callchecker-perl libdevel-globaldestruction-perl  
libdigest-bubblebabble-perl libdouble-conversion1  
libdynaloader-functions-perl libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19  
libemail-valid-perl libexporter-tiny-perl libfcgi-perl  
libfile-find-rule-perl libfuture-perl libgle3 libgnome-desktop-3-17  
libgssdp-1.0-3 libgtkspell3-3-0 libgupnp-1.0-4 libigdgmm5  
libimport-into-perl libio-async-loop-epoll-perl libio-async-perl  
libio-pty-perl libio-string-perl libip4tc0 libip6tc0 libipc-run-perl  
libisl19 libjpeg-turbo-progs libjson-c3 liblinux-epoll-perl  
liblist-compare-perl liblist-moreutils-perl libllvm8 liblouisutdml8  
libmodule-runtime-perl libmoo-perl libmutter-4-0 libmysqlclient20  
libnet-dns-perl libnet-dns-sec-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl
libnet-ip-perl   libnumber-compare-perl libparams-classify-perl
libparse-debianchangelog-perl   libpath-tiny-perl libperlio-gzip-perl
libpoppler85 libreadonly-perl   libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer   librole-tiny-perl librsync1
libsereal-decoder-perl libsereal-encoder-perl   libsereal-perl
libstdc++-8-dev libstrictures-perl libstruct-dumb-perl  
libsub-exporter-progressive-perl libsub-quote-perl libtagc0  
libtest-fatal-perl libtest-refcount-perl libtext-glob-perl  
libtext-levenshtein-perl libtype-tiny-perl libtype-tiny-xs-perl  
libunicode-utf8-perl libvpx5 libx265-165 libxml-simple-perl  
libyaml-libyaml-perl lintian multiarch-support patchutils
python-fasteners   python-lockfile python-monotonic python-six t1utils
xscreensaver-data   xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl
xscreensaver-gl-extra Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. The
following additional packages will be installed:  
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic The following NEW packages will
be installed:   linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic 0 to upgrade, 1
to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade. 7 not fully
installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/38.3 MB of archives. After this
operation, 188 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want
```

to continue? [Y/n]

Of course I enter "Y"
and here's what happened next

```
(Reading database ... 277005 files and directories currently
installed.) Preparing to unpack
.../linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic_5.3.0-45.37_amd64.d eb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic (5.3.0-45.37) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error:
compressed data  is corrupt dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess
returned error exit status 2 dpkg: error processing archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.3.0
-45-generic_5.3.0-45.37_amd64.deb (--unpack):  cannot copy extracted data for './lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/m
edia/dvb-frontends/cx24120.ko' to
'/lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/
media/dvb-frontends/cx24120.ko.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or
stream Errors were encountered while processing: 
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic_5.3.0-45.37_amd64.
deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So it would seem that I cannot update or upgrade because of some dpkg problem

Any tips or clues ?

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

linux-image-generic: Depends: linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic but it is not installed
```

I have no 3rd party repositories

1. What a mess indeed !

   sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop --fix-missing
   [sudo] password for ****: 
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.440.1).
   You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)

.

2. **sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic**

and we're back to

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done The following packages were automatically
>   installed and are no longer required:   chromium-browser-l10n
>   command-not-found-data diffstat g++-8 gir1.2-mutter-4
>   intltool-debian libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg-perl libapt-pkg5.0
>   libarchive-zip-perl libasync-mergepoint-perl libb-hooks-op-check-perl 
>   libcapture-tiny-perl libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl
>   libclass-accessor-perl   libclass-method-modifiers-perl
>   libclass-xsaccessor-perl libclone-perl   libcrystalhd3
>   libdevel-callchecker-perl libdevel-globaldestruction-perl
>   libdigest-bubblebabble-perl libdouble-conversion1
>   libdynaloader-functions-perl libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19
>   libemail-valid-perl libexporter-tiny-perl libfcgi-perl
>   libfile-find-rule-perl libfuture-perl libgle3 libgnome-desktop-3-17
>   libgssdp-1.0-3 libgtkspell3-3-0 libgupnp-1.0-4 libigdgmm5
>   libimport-into-perl libio-async-loop-epoll-perl libio-async-perl
>   libio-pty-perl libio-string-perl libip4tc0 libip6tc0 libipc-run-perl
>   libisl19 libjpeg-turbo-progs libjson-c3 liblinux-epoll-perl
>   liblist-compare-perl liblist-moreutils-perl libllvm8 liblouisutdml8
>   libmodule-runtime-perl libmoo-perl libmutter-4-0 libmysqlclient20
>   libnet-dns-perl libnet-dns-sec-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl
>   libnet-ip-perl   libnumber-compare-perl libparams-classify-perl
>   libparse-debianchangelog-perl   libpath-tiny-perl libperlio-gzip-perl
>   libpoppler85 libreadonly-perl   libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl
>   libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer   librole-tiny-perl librsync1
>   libsereal-decoder-perl libsereal-encoder-perl   libsereal-perl
>   libstdc++-8-dev libstrictures-perl libstruct-dumb-perl
>   libsub-exporter-progressive-perl libsub-quote-perl libtagc0
>   libtest-fatal-perl libtest-refcount-perl libtext-glob-perl
>   libtext-levenshtein-perl libtype-tiny-perl libtype-tiny-xs-perl
>   libunicode-utf8-perl libvpx5 libx265-165 libxml-simple-perl
>   libyaml-libyaml-perl lintian multiarch-support patchutils
>   python-fasteners   python-lockfile python-monotonic python-six t1utils
>   xscreensaver-data   xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl
>   xscreensaver-gl-extra Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. The
>   following NEW packages will be installed:
>   linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic 0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install,
>   0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade. 7 not fully installed or removed.
>   Need to get 0 B/38.3 MB of archives. After this operation, 188 MB of
>   additional disk space will be used. (Reading database ... 277005 files
>   and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
>   .../linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic_5.3.0-45.37_amd64.d eb ...
>   Unpacking linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic (5.3.0-45.37) ...
>   dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error:
>   compressed data  is corrupt dpkg-deb: error:  subprocess
>   returned error exit status 2 dpkg: error processing archive
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.3.0
>   -45-generic_5.3.0-45.37_amd64.deb (--unpack):  cannot copy extracted data for './lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/m
>   edia/dvb-frontends/cx24120.ko' to
>   '/lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/
>   media/dvb-frontends/cx24120.ko.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or
>   stream Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic_5.3.0-45.37_amd64.
>   deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please use {} (*or code*) tags.  Were there any errors for the `sudo apt update` command? or anything unusual?  Is you are using a mirror, is it up-to-date* or have you checked? (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)

Comment: I don't know what to make of the error "UNEXPECTED END OF FILE OR STREAM"

Comment: I'm using  a local mirror that reports up-to-date

Comment: No errors - Fetched 1,278 kB in 4s (294 kB/s)                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... What a mess! Here's a fix: If you're on kubuntu for example, try `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop --fix-missing` and if you're on ubuntu try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop --fix-missing` and so on. When that doesn't work, try `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic`. If none of that works, tell me what error you get.

Comment: error: subprocess returned error exit status 2 dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.3.0 -45-generic_5.3.0-45.37_amd64.deb (--unpack): cannot copy extracted data for './lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/m edia/dvb-frontends/cx24120.ko' to '/lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/ media/dvb-frontends/cx24120.ko.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-45-generic_5.3.0-45.37_amd64. deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @Saywot what? that literally makes NO sense.

Comment: It's up in the original (edited) post

Answer (score -2):

Your module `linux-modules-extra` is not available any more from Eoan. This means the kernel needs to be set up from scratch. I propose two solutions:

1. Back up all the data and do a fresh installation. This build the kernel with the module available and is the faster solution.
2. Dig in the deep and find the device affected. Usually is a network device. I had a similar issue with a railteck wi-fi modem in the past.
   If you choose the second way you need a lot of time.